# Shiny app, only showing some graphs

Tags: r, forecasting, shiny

I am using shiny app to make some forecast graphs. However, I have a problem that the app only shows some graphs. I am currently using the following code for the server part of the app.

```
server <- function(input, output) {  

 output$graph <- renderPlot({
      row.number <- which(grepl(input$n1, Data$Kontotal))
      name <- Data [row.number, -(1:3)]
      name <- t(name)
      name <- ts(name, frequency=12, start=c(2007,1))
      n.row <- nrow(name)

      en<-max(time(name))
      ds<-as.data.frame(window(name,end=en))
      names(ds)<-'obs'
      ds$date<-as.Date(time(window(name,end=en)))     


       p1a <- ggplot(data=ds,aes(x=date,y=obs)) 
       p1a <- p1a+geom_line(col='red')
       p1a <- p1a+scale_x_date(name='',breaks='1 year',minor_breaks='1 month',labels=date_format("%b-%y"),expand=c(0,0))
       p1a <- p1a+scale_y_continuous(name='mio.kr')
       p1a <- p1a + theme_bw() + 
            theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
                  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                  axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) })


 output$graph2 <- renderPlot({

  if (input$n3 == "HW") { 
           row.number <- which(grepl(input$n1, Data$Kontotal))
           name <- Data [row.number, -(1:3)]
           name <- t(name)
           name <- ts(name, frequency=12, start=c(2007,1))
           n.row <- nrow(name)


           fit <- auto.arima (name)
           fcast <- forecast(fit, input$n2)



           ### Plotting

           data.pred <- forc.ggplot (name, fcast)




           p1a <- ggplot(data=data.pred,aes(x=date,y=obs)) 
           p1a <- p1a+geom_line(col='red')
           p1a <- p1a+geom_line(aes(y=fitted),col='blue')
           p1a <- p1a+geom_line(aes(y=forecast))+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lo95,ymax=hi95),alpha=.25)
           p1a <- p1a+scale_x_date(name='',breaks='1 year',minor_breaks='1 month',labels=date_format("%b-%y"),expand=c(0,0))
           p1a <- p1a+scale_y_continuous(name='mio.kr')
           p1a <- p1a + theme_bw() + 
                theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
                      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                      axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
           p1a


      }  

  if (input$n3 == "arima") { 
        row.number <- which(grepl(input$n1, Data$Kontotal))
        name <- Data [row.number, -(1:3)]
        name <- t(name)
        name <- ts(name, frequency=12, start=c(2007,1))
        n.row <- nrow(name)


        fit <- auto.arima (name)
        fcast <- forecast(fit, input$n2)



        ### Plotting

        data.pred <- forc.ggplot (name, fcast)




        p1a <- ggplot(data=data.pred,aes(x=date,y=obs)) 
        p1a <- p1a+geom_line(col='red')
        p1a <- p1a+geom_line(aes(y=fitted),col='blue')
        p1a <- p1a+geom_line(aes(y=forecast))+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lo95,ymax=hi95),alpha=.25)
        p1a <- p1a+scale_x_date(name='',breaks='1 year',minor_breaks='1 month',labels=date_format("%b-%y"),expand=c(0,0))
        p1a <- p1a+scale_y_continuous(name='mio.kr')
        p1a <- p1a + theme_bw() + 
             theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
                   panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                   panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                   axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
        p1a


   }  


 })
```

}

The problem is that only the ARIMA graph is showing. **Note**, however, that in the code posted here I changed the model in the HW-part of the code, so it is identical with the ARIMA part (including the model), just to check that it was because something was wrong with the ets function (which I used to estimate the HW model).

It simply leaves a blank space where the graph should have been in the case of HW, but plots the right graph for the ARIMA model.

Anyone tried anything similar?

Comment: please post the `ui.r`

Answer (score 0):

Put `p1a` at the end of your `renderPlot()` chunk outside the `if` blocks. `renderPlot` attempts to plot the chunks last expression. In case of `input$n3 =="HW"` you generate your Plotting object `p1a` but then continue to evaluate the next `if` condition which is `FALSE` and thus nothing is passed to `plotOutput()`.

An alternative solution would to use `switch()` instead of `if`. `switch()` only evaluates the expression of the matched element.